# Find string in range and return its row number in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have a UserForm with a ListBox (`lbxNames`) of names. On the spreadsheet, I have a range of names (`rngNames`). 
I want to find the row number of the name picked in the ListBox in the list `rngNames` and assign it to `varRowNum`. I can get the ListBox choice OK, but don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us what you had done instead of just asking for solution. By the way, you may take a look at [here] (http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=85615) to get your starting idea

Comment: Hi @Oldman1950, does my solution work for you?

Comment: Thanks nhee works a charm. I just have to work out how it does it now.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** This worked for me.

```
Set TargetCell = Range("rngNames").Find(What:= ENTER_LISTBOXVALUE_HERE, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False)
varRowNum = TargetCell.Row
```

In case you are looking for the *relative* row number within `rngNames` use this instead:

```
varRowNum = TargetCell.Row - Range("rngNames").Cells(1, 1).Row + 1
```

**Result:**

*Absolute* row number in worksheet:
[image]

*Relative* row number in `rngNames`:
[image]

**Explanation:** The `.Find` method will return a cell object of the first occurrence of the search term. The `.Row` property will give you the row number of the found cell within its worksheet. For the relative number, you can simply substract the row number of the first cell of the range (`.Cells(1,1).Row`) from the absolute row number.